# JSP page not displaying the content of web page when deployed on server but when open directly in browser, it works fine

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat

I am a beginner in Web projects. I have created a jsp using CSS and Jquery for styling. I am loading the page on startup of my Web Application. When I open the jsp directly from its location it works fine. Images are displayed properly, styling is properly done, but when I deploy my Web Application on Server it does not show the images, nor the styling. But the hyper links on the page are working as desired.

Jquery and CSS are in different folders.

Update:

```
/WEB-INF/Pages/css
/WEB-INF/Pages/jquery
/WEB-INF/Pages/images
/WEB-INF/Pages/home.jsp
```

tomcat version used is v7.0

Comment: please elaborate the question to include the relevant code, your project structure?

Comment: What do you mean by open jsp directly? Browser can't read jsp directly

Comment: I am entering the path "file:///C:/Users/Tushar/workspace/PhotoJournel/WebContent/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp" in chrome. The data on the page is static as of now.

Comment: You need to move the Pages folder and its contents into the root folder of your web app. Contents of the WEB-INF folder are not accessible to a browser. It is a security restraint.

Comment: @rickz thks for your input. It worked.